# What is the significance of using cold conc H2S04 followed by boiling water for hydration of alkenes?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I tried searching the internet but I failed to find a answer  satisfactory to my understanding.

I know if I react the alkene with cold conc. H2SO4 I get an alkyl hydrogensulfate which upon reaction with boiling water gives alcohol,but I can't understand the need for these conditions like what if we reverse them.

I think that since alkene is nonpolar we react it with sulphuric acid to make the carbocation instead of direct reaction with water,but I dont understand the formation of alkyl hydrogen sulphate.If a carbocation has been formed, water can attack it easily forming an alcohol (assuming that HSO4- is weaker nucleophile than water).So why don't we just add both sulphuric acid and water combined?

Comment: Sulfuric acid is an oxidising agent as well as a strong acid. Using hot sulfuric acid will result in oxidation of the alkene giving a complex mixture.

Comment: then why is there the need for boiling water,H2SO4 is non-nucloephillic acid so H20 is free to act as a nucloephile

Comment: Hydrogensulfate is not that great a leaving group - remember it is still acidic and will protonate the water

Comment: Oh..so here is what I have concluded (correct me if I am wrong)   In hydration of alkenes we react alkenes(non polar) with sulphuric acid first(as direct reaction of water is not possible)~the cold and concentrated conditions favours maximum production of alkyl hydrogen sulphate without oxidizing alkenes.Then we react alkyl hydrogensulfate with boiling water (perhaps boiling water makes hydrogen sulphate a better LG?) and thus water reacts with it forming h30+ and OH- which then attacks on alkyl carbocation forming alcohol.

Comment: wait, shouldn't Hydrogen sulphate be a better leaving group as it is weak conjugate base of a strong acid?

Comment: Hydrogen sulfate will protonate the water meaning that you are trying to make a species leave that is already negatively charged so it has to leave as a dianion. Compare with methanesulfonate which is an excellent leaving group

Comment: so heat favours removal of dianion?

Comment: Heat makes it possible.